# FBNavigation in Android

Tags: android, navigation, actionbarsherlock, fragment

I am using [this](https://github.com/johnkil/SideNavigation) library. its working. but how can i change to the new fragment/activity while keeping same state. below is the code where user can select menu item & it changes the icon within same page. but i want to load new page. how can i do this like fb in android.

```
@Override
    public void onSideNavigationItemClick(int itemId) {
        switch (itemId) {
            case R.id.side_navigation_menu_item1:
                invokeActivity(getString(R.string.title1), R.drawable.ic_android1);
                break;

            case R.id.side_navigation_menu_item2:
                invokeActivity(getString(R.string.title3), R.drawable.ic_android3);
                break;


            default:
                return;
        }
        finish();
    }



private void invokeActivity(String title, int resId) {

      Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_TITLE, title);
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_RESOURCE_ID, resId);
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MODE, sideNavigationView.getMode() == Mode.LEFT ? 0 : 1);

        // all of the other activities on top of it will be closed and this
        // Intent will be delivered to the (now on top) old activity as a
        // new Intent.
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

        startActivity(intent);
        // no animation of transition
        overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/)  tutorial.It works like charm